# addEventListener: How to access event

Tags: javascript, binding, event-handling, this, addeventlistener

I have two questions for the following example:

```
function doIt(){
  this.attribute = someValue; // Works as expected
  alert(event.which); // Doesn't work
}
element.addEventListener("click",doIt,false);
```

Question 1:  Why is `this` bound to the function but `event` is not?
Question 2:  What would be the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is a built-in for JavaScript. It is always accessible. `event` is not. It is only available if the current method supports it.

You would need to have something like

```
function doIt(event)
```

What is `this`? - http://howtonode.org/what-is-this

Comment: I realize `this` is built in, but I don't understanding how `this` can refer back to the element, I thought it should refer to the function itself.  I tried addEventListener("click",function(){doit(event);} which fixes `event` but breaks `this`.  It just seems like there would be a better way than passing both.  Sorry, binding is something I'm struggling to grasp...

Comment: `this` refers to the current `object`, your method is not an object, it's a `method`. Therefore, the only `object` available is the selected element.

Comment: Take a look at these docs that explain `this` is passed from the caller to the function. Below they have the prototype so you can se how the code works - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#section_8

Comment: Hmmm...  you're right, simply doIt(event); works but I haven't grasped why.  I guess I have more homework.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Fantabulum - for the event the caller is passing along the event argument to your function. This is really something you just 'know' from experience or have to rely on documentation to know. Javascript allows you to pass as many arguments as you want to a function, regardless of whether the definition actually uses them. So `doIt() : doIt(event) : doIt(event, b, c, d)` would all be valid